# What's the difference between the various lost phone apps?

Tags: applications, security, lost-phone

I want to get a security app for my phone. I mostly need something in case my phone gets lost or stolen.

Researching this I have found several apps:

- [iTag](http://www.itag.com/login.htm)
- [WaveSecure](https://www.wavesecure.com/)
- [LookOut](https://www.mylookout.com/)

I am sure there are more out there too.

My question is why would I choose one of these over the others.
How do they differ? Does anyone have experience with wiping or finding a lost phone using one of these devices?

Thanks!

Comment: I use LookOut and have tested the lost phone function which works pretty well.  I need to upgrade my version of CM as soon as I have the time.  Before I do I'll try to remotely wipe my device and report back.

Comment: I'm using Prey myself. I'd just look at each one of them, check their features and see if they meet your needs.

Comment: What phone do you have? Some manufacturers (eg HTC and Samsung) make their own tracking apps that they embed in their newer phones. I have a Galaxy S and have Samsung Dive set up for mobile tracking.

Comment: I have a Galaxy S too, The AT&T Captivate. What's the Samsung Dive?

Comment: @Adam http://samsungdive.com/ integrates with the Mobile Tracker section under Location and Security in the phone's settings. Unfortunately I don't think that it's available on all of the US Galaxy S variants for some reason. According to this it should be coming to US AT&T Captivates "soon" http://www.theandroidsoul.com/2010/07/02/samsung-dive-unplugged-on-the-galaxy-s-enhances-security-features/

Comment: @GAThrawn - Yeah, Froyo is supposed to come to my phone "soon"; I'm still waiting. Oh well. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @Adam Mobile Tracker/Samsung Dive isn't specifically a Froyo thing, your phone company may be linking it with their Froyo release, but in Europe we had Dive and Mobile Tracking on Eclair. There's a chance they could give you access to this before Froyo.

Answer (score 2):

I suggest LookOut.  I use it and it's quite good.  It also has the virus scanner and backup of data.