# What is the best pre-stealing practice?

Tags: security, remote-wipe

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is there a way to block access to or wipe my Google data for a lost/stolen phone](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/12608/is-there-a-way-to-block-access-to-or-wipe-my-google-data-for-a-lost-stolen-phone)

I would like to know what is the best/recommended practice to prepare myself to the day when my smartphone (Samsung Galaxy Ace) will be stolen.

In the ideal world I would like to be able to accomplish (in order of importance):

1. Secure my personal data stored on the phone. In particular, by personal data I mean emails accounts, calendar etc. Furthermore, by *secure* I can live with remotely *permanently erase* the sensitive data.
2. Enhance the chances of retrieving the phone. This can be accomplished basing on:

   - Physically locating the phone (using GPS)
   - Communicate with the finder/thief
   - Turing my phone into as unique one (making loud noises or blinking screen)
3. Remotely manage/access the phone

These are the main things I could think of as important in this future case. If you think I missed something, feel free to correct me. If I used non standard terminology please let me know.

Thanks.

Comment: There are, like, lots of questions about this kind of thing on this site. Have you read them? Do you find them inadequate or leaving you with further questions? A selected few: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/2492/981, http://android.stackexchange.com/q/3494/981, http://android.stackexchange.com/q/18644/981, http://android.stackexchange.com/q/19444/981

Comment: One more pretty good one: http://android.stackexchange.com/q/12608/981

Comment: Those applications are good in theory. My suggestion, write down your [IMEI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Mobile_Equipment_Identity). If your phone is stolen, report it to your carrier. This wont necessarily stop anything if it is a GSM device, but couldn't hurt. Any of the apps that claim to help you track your device down after stolen are basically useless. I could take the phone and have the battery out before I walk out the door. Then once I am clear, I can pop out the SIM, turn the device back on, and do a full data wipe. any app you installed to track is gone.

Comment: What Ryan said. Your efforts are better oriented towards damage control, not prevention. Use per-application protection (e.g. PIN codes, in-app passwords) where available. [Application-specific password](http://android.stackexchange.com/questions/19547/how-to-protect-my-google-account/) for your associated Google account is also strongly recommended and will prevent locking yourself out of your Google account, at the very least.

Answer (score 1):

There is an app named [lookout](https://www.mylookout.com/wheres-my-droid/) that can track your device for you using geo - coordinates, and can remotely wipe all data from your device, using mylookout.com from your pc.

Wheres my droid will make your device ring (if not on silence). For more information, you can visit [this link](http://wheresmydroid.com/). If you have anymore questions, I'd be more than happy to answer them.

Answer (score 0):

The app [Prey Anti-Theft](http://preyproject.com) is made for exactly this purpose:

> Prey lets you keep track of your laptop, phone and tablet whenever stolen or missing -- easily and all in one place. It's lightweight, open source software that gives you full and remote control, 24/7.

Application available from [Google Play Store](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.prey).

[image]